# link structures LDR PEB

Tags: assembly, structure, shellcode

I need the address of kernel32.dll via PEB , things get complicated when I try to access the _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY structure by means of a doubly linked list that gives me the _PEB_LDR_DATA structure , these lists are these:

```
+0x00c InLoadOrderModuleList : _LIST_ENTRY
+0x014 InMemoryOrderModuleList : _LIST_ENTRY
+0x01c InInitializationOrderModuleList : _LIST_ENTRY
```

Say for example InMemoryOrderModuleListy selected list LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY need to access structure, that has to be done through Flink show whose structure is as follows:

```
0:000> dt ntdll!_LIST_ENTRY
   +0x000 Flink            : Ptr32 _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x004 Blink            : Ptr32 _LIST_ENTRY
```

In short, do not know if the select list would InMemoryOrderModuleList and pointing directly to the first input LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY as this list is the " LIST_ENTRY type " Flink member and having an offset of 0 and be pointing to that table.

This is the code I try to understand that obtains the address of kernel32 :

```
xor ebx, ebx            //clear ebx
mov ebx, fs:[ 0x30 ]    //get a pointer to the PEB
mov ebx, [ ebx + 0x0C ] //get PEB->Ldr
mov ebx, [ ebx + 0x14 ] //get PEB->Ldr.InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink(1st entry) **here**       
mov ebx, [ ebx ]        //get the next entry(2nd entry)
mov ebx, [ ebx ]        //get the next entry(3rd entry)
mov ebx, [ ebx + 0x10 ] //get the 3rd entries base address(kernel32.dll)
```

As indicated in the line put "here" is what brings me confusion as the moving 0x14 only I 'd selecting the type of InMemoryOrderModuleList list but as you can see in the commentary already in the first inning by putting which has Flink exercised .

I am awaiting your confirmation, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Assume the PEB is at 1000h.

The first members of the PEB are listed here, along with their address in memory

```
typedef struct _PEB {
  /* 1000h + 000h = 1000h */    BYTE Reserved1[2];
  /* 1000h + 002h = 1002h */    BYTE BeingDebugged;
  /* 1000h + 003h = 1003h */    BYTE Reserved2[1];
  /* 1000h + 004h = 1004h */    PVOID Reserved3[2];
  /* 1000h + 00ch = 100ch */    PPEB_LDR_DATA Ldr;
  ...
} PEB, *PPEB;
```

The `Ldr` member is a **pointer**, assume that it points to 2000h,
 i.e. that the `PEB_LDR_DATA` is located at 2000h.

Now from, MSDN, the `PEB_LDR_DATA` has this structure (many members are omitted in the official documentation)

```
typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA {
  /* 2000h + 000h = 2000h */ BYTE       Reserved1[8];
  /* 2000h + 008h = 2008h */ PVOID      Reserved2[3];
  /* 2000h + 014h = 2014h */ LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
} PEB_LDR_DATA, *PPEB_LDR_DATA;
```

As you can see the member `InMemoryOrderModuleList` **is not a pointer** is structure, so all the members of `LIST_ENTRY` are embedded into the `PEB_LDR_DATA` structure.
This means that at the address of `InMemoryOrderModuleList` there is the first member of `LIST_ENTRY`, such member is `Flink` and it is located at 2014h.

```
Here the expanded structure

typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA {
  /* 2000h + 000h = 2000h */ BYTE       Reserved1[8];
  /* 2000h + 008h = 2008h */ PVOID      Reserved2[3];
  /* 2000h + 014h = 2014h */ LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
       /* 2000h + 014h = 2014h */ LIST_ENTRY* InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink
       /* 2000h + 018h = 2018h */ LIST_ENTRY* InMemoryOrderModuleList.Blink
} PEB_LDR_DATA, *PPEB_LDR_DATA;
```

**Note** that now the `Flink` and `Blink` members are **pointers**.

Now suppose that the `InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink` points to 3000h.
At 3000h there is a `LIST_ENTRY` structure, this is the **first** entry.

Suppose that this structure `Flink` member points to 4000h, this is the second entry.
Suppose also that this last structure `Flink` member points to 5000h, this is the third entry.

Now apart from the list head in the `PEB_LDR_DATA`, every `LIST_ENTRY` is actually a `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY`, this is possible since the latter has a compatible memory layout with the former.
So one you reached the entry of interest you can access the member of the `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` structure.

Since the third entry is at 5000h and the `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` has this layout

```
typedef struct _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY {
    /* 5000h + 000h = 5000h */  PVOID Reserved1[2];
    /* 5000h + 008h = 5008h */  LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderLinks;
    /* 5000h + 010h = 5010h */  PVOID Reserved2[2];
    /* 5000h + 018h = 5018h */  PVOID DllBase;
    ...
} LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, *PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY;
```

An ugly MS Paint picture of the situation

[image: Linked list layout]

Reviewing your assembly code

```
xor ebx, ebx            //An useless instruction
mov ebx, fs:[ 0x30 ]    //get a pointer to the PEB
;EBX is now  1000h

mov ebx, [ ebx + 0x0C ] //get PEB->Ldr
;This read from 100ch and EBX gets 2000h

mov ebx, [ ebx + 0x14 ] //get PEB->Ldr.InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink(1st entry)
;This read from 2014h and EBX gets 3000h   

mov ebx, [ ebx ]        //get the next entry(2nd entry)
;This read from 3000h and EBX gets 4000h  

mov ebx, [ ebx ]        //get the next entry(3rd entry)
;This read from 4000h and EBX gets 5000h  

mov ebx, [ ebx + 0x10 ] //get the 3rd entries base address(kernel32.dll)
;This read from 5010h, it seems that this DOES NOT read the correct member! 
;Should be at offset 18h
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the InMemoryOrderModuleList list is the LIST_ENTRY type and its first member is Flink whose displacement is **0x00** ?

```
0:000> dt ntdll!_LIST_ENTRY
   **+0x000** Flink            : Ptr32 _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x004 Blink            : Ptr32 _LIST_ENTRY
```

nMemoryOrderModuleList is a doubly linked list whose first member is Flink and its displacement is 0x00 ... That means that if I select the list InMemoryOrderModuleList would be pointed directly at InMemoryOrderModuleList member _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY table? and and not the beginning of the _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY table?

I apologize if I am not not understand English well, sorry